# Lightning Web Component (LWC) for Visualforce was fails to run

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

Just follow the official document.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_visualforce

I created an aura application - lwcvf.app

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:button"/>
</aura:application>
```

And, add a new visualforce page

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:lwcvf", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:button",
              { label : "Press Me!" },
              "lightningvf",
              function(cmp) {
                console.log("button was created");
              }
          );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

But the result is failed and the error message is **Lightning out App error in callback function**

[image: C]

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo in code mentioned in the documentation example.

The correct code is as below

```
<apex:page>
<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lightning" />

  <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:lwcvf", function () {
        $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:button",
            { label: "Press Me!" },
            "lightning",
            function (cmp) {
                console.log("button was created");
            }
        );
    });
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Notice that the "**lightning**" is the ID of the domLocator where lightning out DOM should be injected and not "*lightningvf*"

Comment: Or, said the typo is the line --> <div id="lightning" /> ==> <div id="lightningvf" />.

Comment: yep , it could be also that :)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: you are welcome